# How can I write the below htaccess rewrite rule for different urls

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am working on a website created using PHP.

Development environment is Windows (using xampp)

The pages of website are displayed according to the value of the "page" variable that we pass to the index.php file as a url variable.

i.e. **`http://example.com/index.php?page=xyz`**

The url above points to the `xyz.php` file

There are around 50 pages (can be increased in future).

I want my urls to be like this

**`http://example.com/xyz`**

for this to work I wrote the following `.htaccess rule` in the .htaccess file (in the root folder of project)

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But it is not working at all.

Another url is 
**`http://example.com/index.php?page=abc&name=gaurav&id=10&page_no=2`**

I want this url to be shown like this

**`http://example.com/abc/gaurav/10/2`**

There are many different forms of the url that I took example of but the page variable will always be there in the URL.

If I provide the rule for both the above urls then nothing works (500 internal server error is shown)

Please help me write this rule.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

So a + instead of a star. It will use all characters till he finds a forward slash (/)

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesnot work 500 internal server error.

Comment: @Gaurav Sharma

Sorry, my mistake. I've changed my code in the post above. This works on my local setup. I strongly suggest that this is the last RewriteRule in your htaccess.

Comment: Now the value of url variable "page" is lost totally. Now this value is static for all pages i.e. index.php.. Also the rule above is not working for this url "http://example.com/xyz/gaurav/10"

Comment: If you read my answer, you'll see it will use all characters till he finds a forward slash. If you want more variables you need to add them.

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&var2=$2

etc

Comment: and what will happen when the variables are less? i.e. i have mentioned 4 variables in the rewrite rule and I am providing only 2 of them.